# Second argument of three mandatory

Tags: python-3.x, function, python-3.6

I have a function that mimics range().  I am stuck at one point.  I need to be able to make the first (x) and third (step) arguments optional, but the middle
argument (y) mandatory.  In the code below, everything works except the two commented out lines.

If I am only passing in one argument, how do I construct the function to accept the single passed in argument as the mandatory (y) argument?

I cannot do this:  def float_range(x=0, y, step=1.0):

Non-default parameter cannot follow a default parameter.

```
def float_range(x, y, step=1.0):
    if x < y:
        while x < y:
            yield x
            x += step
    else:
        while x > y:
            yield x
            x += step


for n in float_range(0.5, 2.5, 0.5):
    print(n)

print(list(float_range(3.5, 0, -1)))

for n in float_range(0.0, 3.0):
    print(n)

# for n in float_range(3.0):
#     print(n)
```

Output:

`0.5
1.0
1.5
2.0
[3.5, 2.5, 1.5, 0.5]
0.0
1.0
2.0`

Comment: My problem is when only one argument is passed in.  In the above code, the only lines I can't get to work are the commented out lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use sentinel values:

```
def float_range(value, end=None, step=1.0):
    if end is None:
        start, end = 0.0, value
    else:
        start = value

    if start < end:
        while start < end:
            yield start
            start += step
    else:
        while start > end:
            yield start
            start += step

for n in float_range(0.5, 2.5, 0.5):
    print(n)
#  0.5
#  1.0
#  1.5
#  2.0

print(list(float_range(3.5, 0, -1)))
#  [3.5, 2.5, 1.5, 0.5]

for n in float_range(0.0, 3.0):
    print(n)
#  0.0
#  1.0
#  2.0

for n in float_range(3.0):
    print(n)
#  0.0
#  1.0
#  2.0
```

By the way, `numpy` implements `arange` which is essentially what you are trying to reinvent, but it isn't a generator (it returns a numpy array)

```
import numpy

print(numpy.arange(0, 3, 0.5))
# [0.  0.5 1.  1.5 2.  2.5]
```